# null check in try catch

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, try-catch

I have a try catch block in my WCF service method that contains an if check on an object. The object 'objRequest' comes in as a service operation input parameter. This is the  code:

```
try
{
    if (objRequest == null)
    {
        //the lines here dont execute even though objRequest is null
        ...
        ...
    }

    //remaining code here
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

Now comes the strange part. If I put that if check outside the try block, the if check works.

```
if (objRequest == null)
{
 //This 'if' check returns true when outside the try block and the line now executes.
  .....
  ....

}
try
{


    //remaining code here
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

Clipped an image here to prove what I am saying. If the object is null, why did it go into the else block?
[image]

I find this magical, and not in a good way. What am I missing here?

Comment: Aside from everything else you should probably be throwing a `NullReferenceException` rather than a general `Exception` in this case.

Comment: So your question is..? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Dan: you should typically not throw `NullReferenceException` but rather `ArgumentNullException` (if `objRequest` is a parameter) or perhaps `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @user20358: The objRequest is not nullable type "int? or bool?" right?

Comment: The if statement evaluates the same whether it is inside or outside the try block. In other words your question is incorrect.

Comment: Could you post the full code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Well actually this is not a question on throwing an exception so much. I am just puzzled as to why my if check works differently within the try block and outside it. I need to clear out some parts from the code before I can post it. will do that soon...

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk Agreed `ArgumentNullException` is better if it is passed as an argument (which wasn't clear when question was first asked).

Comment: @user It doesn't work any different inside or outside of the try.

Comment: Hi David, I know it shouldn't. Do check out the image I've added of my screen. As you can see in the else block, all the object properties are null. That means my object is null. The execution then should have gone into the IF block,... correct?

Comment: No, your object is not null, just the properties inside it!

Comment: Given that your object is not null, your real question should be why in the second code block you posted (if statement outside of try) is the conditional evaluating as true.

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot clearly shows that the object is not null since you can see the values of its properties. Those properties are all null which is what is confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

That's how exception throwing/handling works.

```
try
{
    throw new Exception();
    //remaining code
}
catch (SomeException)
{
    // the exception above will not be caught here
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // however it will be caught here
}
// code here will know nothing about the exception
```

Comment: you did not get my question. The 'if (objREquest==null)' statement equates to false when within the try block. When I put that same statement outside the try block, above it, before the try block starts, it then equates to true. In both cases it is null.

Comment: So my question was how does the 'if' condition act differently when within the try block and outside it.

Comment: @user20358: Something more happens, 100%. Otherwise what you're describing can't be true, sorry.

Comment: @user you are wrong, the try does not change the meaning of the if

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

```
try
{
    if (objRequest == null || default(HereGoesTheobjRequestClassName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Here goes your custom exception message");
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Your catch block here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine.

```
object objRequest = null;
try
{
    if (objRequest == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("details not recieved");
    }
    //remaining code here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Exception");
}
```

**Edit:**

In the screenshot your provided the object is not null, just the properties inside it

Comment: @Jalal He has left out some code, for example which type of exception he is catching. And did I "suspect" that the code would work, yes I did...

Comment: The objRequest is a parameter in my wcf service method. When I test my method thru WCFTestclient, I dont add any values in the test client and invoke it as-is. I also dont have this line "object objRequest = null;" in my code.

Comment: Yes, I thought the wcftestclient would send a null object if I did not set any parameters & I was sure it equated to null when outside the try block, but not otherwise. Never posting a question at 2am again!

Answer (score 1):

The sample code in the question does not show which specific Exception class is caught and also, what happens within the catch block. Perhaps you expect the method to throw an exception but it gets caught in the catch block when you throw it from within the try block. However, if you throw the exception from **outside** the try block, it will not be caught and will be thrown out of the method to the caller.

Comment: reedited my question. The question is not on throwing exceptions. It just my problem with the IF statement. All values with the object are null. Shouldnt my object equate to null then?

Comment: What do you mean by "All values with the object are null"? All the fields of an object may be set to null. That does not make the object reference null.